# Difference between "per" and "according to"

Tags: word-usage

I have two examples:

> - I am assembling this piece of furniture as *per* the attached
>     instructions
> - I am assembling this piece of furniture *according to* the
>     attached instructions

Is there any difference between *per* (meaning *according to*) and *according to* as in the given examples? Can those two words be used interchangeably?

Are there any limitations when one word should be used but not the other?

Comment: You probably want to compare *according to* with *as per*, not just *per*?

Comment: Related on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/54864/50720

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They mean the same in those two examples, and both are grammatical, but I dislike *as per*. To me it sounds stilted and I can think of no occasions on which it is necessary to use it. That, however, is a personal view with which others may disagree.

Comment: I agree about *as per*: it sounds like legalese.

Comment: @Cerberus  It *is* legalese. *And* it is redundant - no *as* is required.

Comment: *As per* is also business-speak and sounds terrible ("stilted", as Barrie said) and pretentious to my ears. Your second sentence is much better than the first.

Comment: @StoneyB: Right. But people often use it with *as*, as per the OP's example. I use *per* only distributively myself, when no other option is possible.

Comment: I might be in the minority here, but ***I*** disagree. I use *per* quite often (with or without preceding *as*) to mean *according to* or *as specified by*, etc. But I will admit it's something of a "mixed register", being partly just a casual usage aiming at brevity, and partly an echo of a more formal "Latinate" style.

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you. It sounds like legalese here but is appropriate in formal setting, like research papers, business report, right?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica For this particular context, would this one be more common? *"I am assembling this piece of furniture, **following** the attached instructions"?*

Comment: @WXJ96163: ***following, per, as per, in accord[ance] with, from,by,...*** I don't see much point in trying to set up a "beauty context" of different prepositional usages here. All that's really relevant is that some people think ***[as] per*** is "jargonny", so maybe some *other* people might avoid it to avoid annoying those fusspots.

Comment: @Cerberus Does "legalese" mean too formal? If yes, I agree that "as per" is too formal for situations like assembling furniture. How about an essay?

Comment: @WXJ96163: 'Legalise' is often used to mean "jargon, only used in that particular domain". I don't think using *as per* in an academic paper would be absurd, but be aware that some people would not like it.

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you. In what domain, people would like it?

Comment: @WXJ96163: Perhaps in law. But, in general, my advice would be this: if you are thinking about using a word or phrase that might sound 'fancy' or sophisticated, only use it if you feel sure about it (or if it is truly necessary). Another thing: style books generally recommend a simple style when possible. Fancy is often not better than simple. But, ultimately, the choice is yours.

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you. I guess I got it. As proof, [synonyms of "according to" listed on the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/topics/communication/quoting-and-making-references/) does not include "as per".

Answer (score 1):

According to [Handling Usually Confused Expressions in English Language](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=Handling%20Usually%20Confused%20Expressions%20in%20English%20Language):

> 'Per' and 'according to' carry the same meaning except that 'per' is
>   used in situations like, 'As per orders of the captain she was taken
>   away from the ship.'

So you should not use 'as per' because, there, 'as per' seems to have an overly imperative sound.