# Is it natural to say "as proof" to convey my agreement and support?

Tags: word-usage

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/proof)

> I'm glad I had the forethought to make a copy of the letter, **as proof** of what had been promised.

[According to an ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/892/109190), some people would not like using "as per" as alternatives to "according to". To agree with and support that point of view, I said

> **As proof**, synonyms of "according to" listed on the Cambridge Dictionary does not include "as per".

Is it natural to say that for this particular situation?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "**As proof**" is natural, but incorrect here, because it's not technically proof for your side of the argument. The Cambridge Dictionary isn't the faultless guide to English and word choice is flexible.

Starting a sentence with "**As proof**" is fine and you used it naturally, but it is misleading in this example.

Proof has a specific definition, and I don't think your example uses it correctly. The way you used it is natural in a grammatical sense, but ensure that what you're referencing directly after is actually proof of something. Starting a sentence with it implies that the following statement is technically correct and it's jarring to read something that isn't a proof instead.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose the list of synonyms in question comes from a widely recognized faultless book named "Faultless English Guide" and does not include "as per". I guess the fact could be proof of "as per" being not an appropriate synonym. How do I make the sentence using "as proof" correct?